# Save a subdomain name to String

Tags: python, subdomain, plone, template-tal, zpt

It's a rather unusual request, but is it possible to extract a subdomain to a variable?

```
e.g.
(1)  sub1.mydomain.com
(2)  sub2.mydomain.com
```

When I click on (1) I want to save "sub1" and vice versa. I use plone (python and tal). Thx for your input.

Comment: sry my bad I use the templates :)

Comment: To be honest I don't know. I created a plonetheme (not with diazo) a standard plone 3 and the browser contained the .py files as well as the .pt's with tal

Comment: That's Zope Page Templates. When you added the Plone tag I understood enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a Python expression to split at the first dot:

```
tal:define="subdomain python:domain.partition('.')[0]"
```

or, if using Python 2.4 or earlier:

```
tal:define="subdomain python:domain.split('.', 1)[0]"
```

This uses [`str.partition()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) or [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to return a list of strings; the local name is the first part; `[0]` selects the first element of that list.

Demo using a Python prompt:

```
>>> 'sub1.mydomain.com'.partition('.')[0]
'sub1'
>>> 'sub1.mydomain.com'.split('.', 1)[0]
'sub1'
```

Comment: Watch out for your Plone version. Python 2.4 (used by Plone 3) will not provide you `.partition`. In that case use `'sub1.mydomain.com'.split('.', 1)[0]`

Comment: @keul: excellent point; I tend to forget that `.partition()` was added in 2.5.

Comment: worked like a charm well I used self.request["URL"] to obtain the url but the rest was fine - thx to both of you